# How do I detect "ÿ" in a string in TCL?

Tags: string, parsing, unicode, tcl

I am querying an old Tektronix 11801B sampling oscilloscope. When I query anything it always returns my result and then an endless string of either "ÿ" on one device or "ÿ.." on another device (both the same model). So, I decided I will read everything before I hit a "ÿ" when querying.

Here are two ways that I have tried:

```
# Issue command
puts ${ChannelId} ${Command}

# Set loop variables
set Result [list]
set Byte [read ${ChannelId} 1]
set BadByte ÿ

# Loop until BadByte is found
while {![string equal -nocase ${Byte} ${BadByte}]} {

    # Append good bytes to a list
    lappend Result ${Byte}

    # Read next byte
    set Byte ::visa::read ${ChannelId} 1]
}

# Join and return result list
return [join ${Result}]
```

And:

```
# Set loop variable
set Result [list]

# Read channel 1 byte at a time until ÿ is found
while {![string equal -nocase [set Character [read ${ChannelId} 1]] "ÿ"]} {

    # Append non ÿ characters to a list
    lappend Result ${Character}
}

# Join the result and return it
return [join ${Result}]
```

In both cases, my loop just always returns true and becomes infinite. However, if I run the commands line by line in wish everything works properly.

Comment: Have you thought about using 'expect' to talk to the Tektronix?  It should be ideal for this sort of application.

Comment: That ÿ is usually a 0xff, maybe configure your channel properly (e.g. setup some translation/encoding with `fconfigure`.

Comment: @lanam I did look into expect a bit and it does sound very tasty, but it looks to no longer be supported and the windows version got dropped a while before the linux version so I don't think it would be a good choice for our application specifically. Thanks for the response though

Comment: @schlenk I'm testing different channel configurations now, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @schlenk I've tried several channel configurations and several encoding options. Nothing seems to be effecting what I'm getting from the device. Do you have any idea why it would work when executing line by line, but not in the while loop?

Comment: Maybe timing. Not sure, haven't done much with serial channels. Did you set the correct parameters to open?

Comment: I'm guessing that `fconfigure $ChannelId -translation binary` would be useful. Then you'll be working with characters that are also bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is *how* you source the file. By default, it uses `encoding system`, which is a problem if you save your file as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). You can see how Tcl sees the `ÿ` char; you could try the following script:

```
binary scan ÿ c* bytes
puts $bytes
```

If the output is not `-1`, then this is indeed the case.

The best way to avoid this is to use `\xff` instead (encode every character outside of the ASCII range). This is a thing that I do not only recommend for Tcl, but also for many other languages like Java, C#, etc.

So you have the following options:

- Use `\xff` instead `ÿ`
- Save your file with the system encoding (opening two files in Tcl with the right encodings & fcopy can do the job)
- Source the file with the right encoding. If invoked with tclsh, use `tclsh -encoding utf-8 yourfile.tcl`. If you use the `source` command, then `source -encoding utf-8 yourfile.tcl`

If all of this does not work, you can try to do a `binary scan` on the input `ÿ` and see what it looks like.

Comment: Okay, when I `binary scan ÿ c* bytes` I do get -1, but when I scan anything that the scope is sending back it gives me `66 121 116 101`. Where would I be use \xff, is that the input for encoding? Also, I'm not reading from files, I'm querying a piece of equipment if that makes a difference to your answer.

Comment: It outputting `66 121 116 101` was just a typing error on my part.

Comment: Alright, this answer works, if you just scan each byte output by the device into integers and then look for a -1 instead of ÿ the script will work and it's not too bulky either. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: and if you add `binary scan ÿ c* chars; puts $chars` in the file? In an interactive session, it should display `-1`, but if you save it in a script?

Comment: @kuhn same, still gives -1 both in wish and running from a script. For some reason the `string equals` procedure just didn't want to match 2 ÿ's, but when I convert the device's output to an integer and compare it to -1: `while {${Integer} != "-1"}` it gives me the desired result.